# What are these two strange queries that keep running on every request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I added miniprofiler to my app and I noticed the following two queries that run on every request regardless of the controller or view:

```
**GET http://acme.app.dev:80
T+4.3 ms
Reader
0.7 ms
              SELECT COUNT(*)
              FROM pg_class c
              LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
              WHERE c.relkind in ('v','r')
              AND c.relname = 'schema_migrations'
              AND n.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))

GET http://acme.app.dev:80/search
T+6.8 ms
Reader
0.2 ms
              SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"   
              4.60 ms   
              Executing action: new — 2.60 ms
```

There's nothing in my app that aught to be running them. What are they and why are they always running? I'm using Rails 4 with Postgresql.

Comment: The `schema_migrations` table tracks which migrations have been run. I can't think of any reason that a profiler would look at that table at all let alone on every request.

Comment: Is it possible it checks migrations are up to date on eveyr request, e.g.`ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)`. Also is mini-profiler doing this query or is Rails doing it anyway? (I suspect Rails)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails 4.0 seems to check for any outstanding migrations on every request. If there are outstanding migrations I get this error in the browser:

```
ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError

Migrations are pending; run 'rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development' to resolve this issue.
```

I would assume this only happens in test/development environment and is most likely the same code which you see in {test, spec}_helper.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)
```